# Changing string color in visual studio doesn't change the quotation mark color. So how do I change that?

Tags: string, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, quotes

When I change the color of a string inside quotation marks in visual studio, it only changes the color of the text. How do you change the color of the quotes too? I've tried changing the color of punctuation but that doesn't work either.

[image: color only changes for text, not quotes]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio: <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Environment</kbd> > <kbd>Fonts and Colors</kbd> > *C++ String - Delimiter Character*.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I confirmed that your translations were correct, so removed the disclaimer. (There was one minor difference—a hyphen instead of a colon in the final option—but I also fixed that while I was at it.)

Comment: How did you change the color of the strings to green like in your screenshot? I've searched in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, but couldn't find anything.